# updating user record when associating providers with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I create a new account through google, the email gets stored in my user record. When I create a user through twitter, the email column is blank.  I'd like to update that entry if a user associates their current twitter account with google.

in my User model:

```
def self.create_from_hash!(hash)
  create! do |user|
    user.name = hash['user_info']['name']
    user.email = hash['user_info']['email']
  end
end
```

In sessions controller:

```
def create
  auth = request.env['rack.auth']
  unless @auth = Authorization.find_from_hash(auth)
    @auth = Authorization.create_from_hash(auth, current_user)
  end
  self.current_user = @auth.user
  flash[:notice] = "Welcome, #{current_user.name}."
  redirect_to '/'
end
```

and in the Authorization model:

```
def self.create_from_hash(hash, user = nil)
  user ||= User.create_from_hash!(hash)
  Authorization.create(:user => user, :uid => hash['uid'], :provider => hash['provider'])
end
```

How can I update that column when I am adding an authorization method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following line into my sessionscontroller create action, which seems to solve the issue:

```
if @user && (@user.email.blank? || @user.email.nil?)
    @user.update_attribute(:email, request.env['rack.auth']['user_info']['email']) unless request.env['rack.auth']['user_info']['email'].nil? || @user.nil?
end
```

Comment: It is enough to do only @user.email.blank? check, why are you doing @user.email.nil?

Comment: @Ivailo Bardarov - I don't exactly recall if it was explicitly necessary to check for nil, but I do have several providers, and multiple methods and I believe that there were cases where @user.email returned nil

Comment: @Ivailo Bardarov - no, blank checks for blank, as I said, I was using multiple providers and multiple auth mechanisms, in some cases email field may be blank, in other cases it may be nil, hence why I checked for both

Comment: According to the RDOC 

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F

An object is blank if it’s false, empty, or a whitespace string. For example, “”, “ ”, nil, [], and {} are blank.

So there is no need to check this twise, once with .nil? and once with blank?.